# How to unit test methods that use threads?

Tags: c#, java, unit-testing, junit, nunit

How to write unit tests for methods that use threads.

In example below how to test someMethod method ?

```
    public class SomeClass {

    private final SomeOtherClass someOtherClassInstance = IoC.getInstance(SomeOtherClass.class);

    private final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

    public void someMethod() {
        executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                someOtherClassInstance.someOtherMethod();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Are there any solutions in java and .net for this purpose?

Comment: The problem you have is not the use of multiple threads but the lack of dependency injection.  Have components which wire themselves makes them much harder to test.  Can you use dependency injection instead?

Comment: You would test the someOtherClassInstance.someOtherMethod() in your unit tests and not someMethod, right?

Comment: what you would want to test is the logic inside your method `someOtherMethod`, not the thread itself. The thread (and the thread pool) are part of the JVM, I assume that the vendor has already tested it! ;)

Comment: @Peter Lawrey. I'm using. IoC.getInstance() is general idiom that i used in this example to not mention any concrete implementation of DI cointaners.

Comment: Sure I can test someOtherMethod. But I would like also to test someMethod. In no-thread environment I would create mock for this, and check if appropriate method in SomeOtherClass was invoked.

Comment: For me DI means you inject your dependencies, not have a component wire itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is another thread, you have wait until the method has been called.  You have to decide how long you should wait before considering the method wasn't called, there is no tool which can do that for you.

Of course you can mock the ExecutorService to run in the current thread and avoid the issue.

Comment: Althought this is the accepted answer, the answer of Rob Smyth better explaines what the TS is facing.

Answer (score 7):

Your question begs 'what is a unit test' (UT). UTs are just one form of automated tests. In this case your question implies that the code calls the OS to start a thread, so by definition, a test that tested it would not be a unit test but probably be an integration test.

Why I bother you with what seems like semantics is that understanding the intent of the test makes it so easy to write the test and structure the code. The amount of working code out there is larger than the amount of testable code out there.

So, how can this code be changed to be unit testable (I will skip the 'why bother stuff') ...

A unit test in C# tests a single type (your class) ... importantly (by definition) nothing else. So your code needs to reflect this. What you want to test is that when I call ABC it does this stuff. Something that stuff includes launching a thread. So you want to test that the method to launch a thread a called. The fundamental here is that your application requires a thread so that is what your asserting.

So how? Create a proxy, and perhaps a factory, for the thread creation. Then you can assert in a unit test that it was called and how it was treated. Sounds hard, but is really easy when you get into the habit.

BTW, Resharper makes creating a proxy for an OS types (e.g. thread). Check out the delegating members stuff in their help. If your not using Resharper you should be.

Yea I know this is not the answer you had hopped for, but believe me it is the answer you need.

I find it useful to think of tests in the categories:

- Unit tests
- Integration tests (or perhaps subsystem tests)
- Functional test (e.g. UI/application/UAT tests)

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough in my question. To be honest I'm not interested in testing thread. What I like to test in this example is to make sure that someOtherMethod() was invoked. In non-thread enviroment I would simply create mock for SomeOtherClass and check if appriopriate method was invoked. But in case there is thread involved then mock library seems to have some problems in correct validation of the test.

Comment: Hi Anth. Your comment matches my understanding so I think I did understand your question. What I'm trying to say is inject a proxy for the OS's thread operation and test that the executor service is called ... and importantly ... with your method.

Comment: @RobSmyth Thanks this was what I was looking for, and it actually clears up the code for testing purposes. With the only downside of adding another dependency to the class.

Answer (score 4):

The jMock Team has described an brilliant approach for Java in the ['jMock Cookbook: Test Multithreaded Code'](http://jmock.org/threads.html). The concept of executing "thread" functionality on the same thread as the test can also be applied to C# code (see [this blog post](http://svengrand.blogspot.de/2013/12/unit-testing-c-code-which-starts-new.html)). The C# test would look like this:

```
[Test]
public void TestMultiThreadingCodeSynchronously()
{
    // Arrange
    SomeOtherClass someOtherClassMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<SomeOtherClass>();
    DeterministicTaskScheduler taskScheduler = new DeterministicTaskScheduler();
    SomeClass systemUnderTest = new SomeClass(taskScheduler, someOtherClassMock);

    // Act
    systemUnderTest.SomeMethod();

    // Now execute the new task on
    // the current thread.
    taskScheduler.RunTasksUntilIdle();

    // Assert
    someOtherClassMock.AssertWasCalled(x=>x.SomeOtherMethod());
}
```

Your "system under test" would look like this:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    private readonly TaskScheduler taskScheduler;
    private readonly SomeOtherClass instance;

    public SomeClass(
        TaskScheduler taskScheduler, 
        SomeOtherClass instance)
    {
        this.taskScheduler = taskScheduler;
        this.instance = instance;
    }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(
          instance.SomeOtherMethod, 
          new CancellationToken(), 
          TaskCreationOptions.None, 
          taskScheduler);
    }
}
```

The C# solution is described in detail in [this blog post](http://svengrand.blogspot.de/2013/12/unit-testing-c-code-which-starts-new.html).